# Converting MP3 to Binary

Tags: java, binary, mp3

I'm just wondering...is it possible to use Java to convert a .mp3 file into a text file of straight up binary (just 1's and 0's)?  I figure it would involve the usage of `AudioInputStream` and then some method to decode individual bytes, but can someone give me an idea on where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Files _are_ binary.  Are you asking to convert raw bits into ASCII `1` and `0` bytes?

Comment: That would be insane. Each output file would be huge!

Comment: @JustinSatyr Only ~8x as large..

Comment: @SLaks yeah, and is there a way to convert them back into the original .mp3?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @SLaks mostly for curiosity. To see what it would sound like if I flipped all the bits/changed values.

Comment: Ah, my code solution isn't useful then.  Get a hex editor like HxD and it can do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I'll accept your answer since you gave me the original idea for the hex editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, but you don't need to use a special audio stream.  What you're looking for is to turn any type of file into a file of 1 and 0 characters.  I have not tested this code, but the algorithm should be clear.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(otherpath));
byte contents[] = new byte[100];
while (fin.read(contents)!= -1)
{
  for (byte b : contents)
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
      bw.write(b>>x & 1);
}
```

Edit:  If you just wanted to see what it looks like, you can open any kind of file with a hex editor.

Comment: If I do this algorithm in reverse, (reading in the individual 1's and 0's, then saving it as whatever type of file I want) will it work too?

Comment: If you try a naive implementation, no.  Notice that it splits the byte into 8 pieces to print 1s and 0s.  They would need to be recombined before that byte was written back to a file.  Something like 'read 8 characters -> convert to 1 byte -> write to file' would do.  If that's the task you want to do though, use an existing solution like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

Answer (score 2):

You should ignore that its a MP3 file. Just treat it as a binary. Read the file byte by byte and convert each byte to its "binary" representation.

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and type xxd -b filename.mp3